# Getting error while running Blockchain.info api

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I am getting error as {"error":"Not found"} when I am trying to run the blockchain.info wallet api service locally on my computer.
I was getting the error of "Address in Use " error when I ran it on http://127.0.0.1:3000/
after changing it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I am getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain.info is really not working anymore, seems to be they are stopping API service or there's something wrong. Since API don't work anymore (callbacks - gap limit so far).